# xsltproc specify search path for input document

Tags: xslt

Can I do this with xsltproc:

- The main document that is being processed is located in directory *`src_dirname`* relative to `$PWD`
- The name of the document to include is specified in the `src` attribute
- If the attribute `origin` is set to

  - `generated`, the document to include should be found in *`target_dir`*`/`*`src_dirname`*`/@src`
  - anything else, the document to include should be found in *`src_dirname`*`/@src`

Tried:

```
<xsl:template match="include">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@origin='generated'">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document(concat($target_dir, '/', $src_dirname, '/', @src))/content" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@src)/content" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

with

```
xsltproc --path . --stringparam target_dir __targets --stringparam src_dirname doc doc/doc2html.xsl doc/maike.doc.xml
```

But it wants to load the resource from `doc/__targets/doc/cmdline.xml`, which is wrong. It should be `__targets/doc/cmdline.xml`.

Tag in input document:

```
<include src="cmdline.xml" origin="generated" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, if the stylesheet is fed through stdin, document will not try to look in the directory of the source file, thus

```
xsltproc --path . --stringparam target_dir __targets --stringparam src_dirname doc - doc/maike.doc.xml < doc/doc2html.xsl
```

Solves the problem